# Hitbox Follower Alert

Tags: live-streaming, twitch

There is this site called hitbox. It's similar to twitch but as far as I can see the api is rather different! I tried to take a twitch follower alert and change the code a bit to make it work with hitbox but with no luck. I don't want to create a whole program because that would take a lot of time. I just want to make a webpage and display the latest follower on there. The hitbox api can be found [here](http://developers.hitbox.tv/followers#u1).
If you think it would be easier to do something like that but in mIRC then do it that way but I think it would be easier to do it with a webpage. I am a total n00b when it comes to programming so if you could explain to me what everything does I would appreciate it (I want to start learing to code but I don't really know where to start. At least I am quite young (14) so I have enough time to do that)

Thanks you
- Andrew

Answer (score 3):

I just came across you post while searching for some information on Hitbox on Google.
And you know what!? I just made a follower alert app like 30 min ago.
Here is the code, actually it's really simple. (hitbox_followeralert.js)

```
var followers = 0,
    lastCheck = 0,
    lastFollower = "",
    sound = new Audio("AlertSound.ogg"),
    channel = "MaitreChocobo";

function checkForNew(){
    $.getJSON("http://api.hitbox.tv/user/"+channel, function(data){
        followers = data.followers;

        if(followers > lastCheck && lastCheck!=0){
            sound.play();
            $.getJSON("http://api.hitbox.tv/followers/user/"+channel+"?offset="+(followers-1), function(gata){

                $("#new-follower").html(gata.followers[0].user_name);

                $("#follower-alert .text").css("font-size", "45px");
                $("#follower-alert").fadeIn("slow");
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $("#follower-alert").fadeOut("slow");
                }, 10000);
            })
        }
        lastCheck = followers;
    }).fail(function(){
        console.log('An error occurred!');
    });
}

setInterval(checkForNew, 5000);
```

Since I inspired myself from the Twitch Follower Alert from NightDev I copied their whole webpage to make everything simpler. Here is the page. (Index.html)

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Follower Alert</title>
    <style>
      body {
        background-color: transparent;
        color: white;
      }

      #follower-alert {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 580px;
        height: 110px;
      }

      #follower-alert .text {
        margin-left: 170px;
        padding-top: 45px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 385px;
        line-height: 45px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-size: 45px;
        font-family: Impact;
        text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #000;
        white-space: nowrap;
        color: #ffffff;
      }
    </style>
  <style type="text/css"></style></head>
<body>
<div id="follower-alert" style="background-image: url(template.png);">
 <div class="text" id="new-follower" style="margin-left: 15px; width: 550px;"></div>
</div>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="hitbox_followeralert.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

You will only have to change the channel variable at the top to match your username.
You could also delete the sound part if you don't need it. I also made a simple background called *template.png* in the root folder. So I have 4 files to make this litte project : index.html, hitbox_followeralert.js, AlertSound.ogg, template.png

Then to add it to OBS I used the plugin called CLR Browser and you're good to go!

Hope this could help you and I'm not too late to answer your question.
-MaitreChocobo